# Calculate the derivative of a complex norm

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, normed-spaces

I'm stuck with a rather trivial looking question. How do you calculate the derivative of the norm of a complex number to it self? Like in

$$
\frac{d|a|^2}{da} = ?
$$

I think it would give rise to a real valued function but in stead I get

$$
\frac{d|a|^2}{da} = \bar{a}
$$

I can't understand this result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A bit misleading question, as the real answer should be $\frac{d|a|^2}{da}=2\bar{a}$

Comment: @eimrek Could you explain how did you arrive at the real answer? The Wirtinger derivative contains a factor of 1/2 and yields the result of the question.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** For $z$ complex

> $$ |z|^2 =z\bar{z}. $$

**Note:**

> $$ z=x+iy \implies \bar{z}=x-iy .$$

Comment: So did i think it was but the meaning of a derivative is that it gives the rate of change. But how could this be complex if the function it self is real? The rate of change has to be real for a real function or am I wrong here?

Comment: @DoubleDouble The Wirtinger derivatives don't give rates of change. At least not in a simple way. If you want a rate of change, compute $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$.

Comment: Very belated, but for future readers: not if the "denominator" (interval) is complex. Consider: if $z$ goes from $0$ to $i$, then while $|z|^2$ goes from $0$ to $1$ (a pure real change), $\Delta |z|^2/\Delta z$ is $1/i = -i$, which is complex.

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is for previous years, I wanted to give a more complete and descriptive answer that might be useful to others.
$$
 \frac{d |a|^2}{da}=\frac{d (a a^{*})}{da}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{d( a a^{*})}{d \Re{a}}-i \frac{d( a a^{*})}{\Im{a}}\right) \\
\frac{1}{2}((a+a^{*})-(a-a^{*}))=a^{*}
$$
$ a$ is complex number in $\mathbf{C}$.

Answer (score 0):

In any Pre-Hilbert-space the map $x\mapsto\|x\|$ is differentiable for $x\ne0$ and it's derivative is $p\mapsto\langle p,x\rangle/\|x\|$.

Comment: Given the level of the question, it seems unlikely to me that this answer is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $x = a+bi$ where $i^2 = -1$. Then, the derivative of $\ell_p$ norm of $x$ (i.e., $\|x\|_p$) is given by

$$d/dx (|x|_p) = d/da (|x|_p) - d/db (|x|_p)i$$

Comment: I think introducing the "$\ell_p$" norm into the question takes us out of the original issue, which is why can the derivative of a real-valued function be complex.

Answer (score -2):

For a complex variable a, |a|^2 derivative exist only at zero. Try evaluating at x_0+i*y_0 not zero. Approach from y=y_0 and you get 2*x_0 but approach from x=x_0 and you get -2*y_0*i. And at zero you get limit r^2 over r*e^(theta*i) that go to zero.